# OS 10.10 not connecting through proxy specified by its Internet name

Tags: macos, dns, internet, proxy

My office proxy has always been specified with its IP address and everything worked fine. However, recently, the proxy was changed to use its Internet name, in the form

```
xxxx-y.zzzz.com
```

Since then, I have been unable to connect. I keep getting infinite authentication dialog boxes, but still doesn't connect. I've opened `/etc/hosts` to add its Internet name and map it to its IP address. It is still failing.

However, if I change back to the legacy numeric iIP address, it connects fine. Problem is that the legacy IP address will soon be discontinued as it has issues.

Answer (score 1):

The alphabetic `xxxx-y.zzzz.com` is a hostname, not an `ip address`, and `hostnames` almost always resolve to an ip address. You should try doing an `nslookup` in `Terminal.app` to confirm whether or not you've got the right information in your hosts file.

```
$ nslookup xxxx-y.zzzz.com 

Non-authoritative answer:
xxxx-y.zzzz.com canonical name = p9p.geo.asbs.yahoodns.net.
Name:    p9p.geo.asbs.yahoodns.net
Address: 98.139.134.174
```

Then in `/etc/hosts` confirm you've got:

```
98.139.134.174   xxxx-y.zzzz.com
```

something tells me `xxxx-y.zzzz.com` is not your real hostname, but you get the idea.

Comment: No luck. I copied the IP address and the name to /etc/hosts, only difference is that the authentication dialog comes just three or 4 times, but browser keeps loading forever

Comment: @Ladmerc, it sounds like a problem with the dns of hostname perhaps; what happens when you try the ip that was output from `nslookup`? If you're still having problems I would inform the administrators that the hostname isn''t working properly.

Comment: When I tried the ip from nslookup, there wasn't any change. The auth dialog came up, I put the credentials, then the browser kept loading.
I informed admin, but somehow every other person on windows can connect, so I'm guessing it's a mac issue

Comment: Maybe post the details of your configuration, such as how the proxy is setup, what your method of authentication is, etc. Without more info it's anyone's guess what the problem might be. Also check in `Console.app` or `~/Library/Logs/` for related error messages.

Comment: Ok, here goes. The network admin provided automatic DNS. I put xxx-y.zzz as Web Proxy Server, with port 8080 (for both http and https). ; specifying the username and password. Initially when the proxy was numeric, this worked fine, but when it changed to the proxy name, it stopped. I also deleted the entire settings from keychain, deleted the proxy and reconnected anew, no luck.

Comment: Normally a proxy running on port `8080` (https) would be either a `SOCKS Proxy` or a `Secure Web Proxy`. `Web Proxy` is usually run on port `80` and is not secure (`http` vs `https`), so you might try one of the other configurations. Also try resetting the `dns` cache for your machine in `Terminal.app`: `sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache`, and report back with any error messages from the log files...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24490/discussion-between-ladmerc-and-lll).